# using "global" variables by loading into a file - twig

Tags: symfony, twig

**Hi, I have a problem with loading variables from a separate file.**

I have a set of components that have the same variables - I pulled them into a separate file to complete them in one file.

The structure looks as follows:

**Global components**

component1.html.twig

```
{% $headerClass = headerClass ?? 'header' %}
{% $descriptionClass = descriptionClass ?? 'description' %}

html structure ...
```

component2.html.twig

```
{% $headerClass = headerClass ?? 'header' %}
{% $descriptionClass = descriptionClass ?? 'description' %}

html structure ...
```

**Extend components in local templates**

component1-local.html.twig

```
{% extend 'global/component1.html.twig' %}
```

component2-local.html.twig

```
{% extend 'global/component2.html.twig' %}
```

**Now in local create global variables:**

global-variables-for-component-1-2.html.twig

```
$headerClass = 'new_header_class'
$descriptionClass = 'new_description_class'
```

And now I want to use the file global-variables-for-component-1-2.html.twig and load it into the files component1-local.html.twig, component2-local.html.twig so that they use the variables specified in global-variables- for-component-1-2.html.twig.

1. When I do it like this:

component1-local.html.twig

```
{{ include('global-variables-for-component-1-2.html.twig') }}

{% extend 'global/component1.html.twig' %}
```

This component does not see the variables from the file global-variables-for-component-1-2.html.twig

2. I can't do 2x extends in one file.

I have no idea how to solve this. - I'm asking for help.

Comment: Can't be done, included templates have their own scope

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use a template to set a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56781651/use-a-template-to-set-a-variable)

Comment: However, you can alter the "context" of twig as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32525041/can-a-twig-simplefunction-modify-the-context)

Comment: Related question and more in-depth answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42148600/twig-add-item-to-array-from-within-an-included-template)